# Скачать и отправить файл с помощью retrofit не сохраняя его

Tags: android, http, retrofit, callback

Использую библиотеку Retrofit. Скачиваю файл, после чего хочу сразу же его отправить на другой адрес. 
В данный момент реализовал с помощью сохранения файла на SD карту, дальнейшей его передачи и удаления. Но хотелось бы без сохранения файла на SD. Как это можно сделать?
Ниже код варианта с сохранением файла.

Настройка Retrofita

```
class AppConfig {
    private static String BASE_URL = "http://..../";

    static Retrofit getRetrofit {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Настройка интерфейса

```
interface Config {
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> dFile(@Url String fileUrl);

    @Multipart
    @POST("send.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> uFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part RequestBody name); 
}
```

Скачивание и отправка

```
String srcFile = "http://..../";
final Config api = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(Config.class);
Call<ResponseBody> callD = api.dFile(srcFile); 

callD.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody>, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            File fileTemp = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "temp_file");
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(fileTemp);
            fileOutput.write(response.body().bytes());
            fileOutput.close();

            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data", fileTemp);
            MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("name", fileTemp.getName(), requestBody);
            RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data", fileTemp.getName);

            callU.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody>, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    fileTemp.delete();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody>, Throwable t) {
                    ...
                } 
        catch(IOException e) {
            ...
        }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody>, Throwable t) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что файл все равно будет *(куда-то на устройстве)* сохраняться?

Comment: А нельзя ли использовать оперативную память? @post_zeew

Comment: А, Вы так хотите. Ну, можно, наверное. Но какой смысл?

Comment: Не хочется терять время на чтение/запись файла в физическую память. @post_zeew

Comment: @shamrushsham на фоне скачивания/отправки, чтение/запись SD просто потеряются и без микроскопа найдены не будут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае можно использовать буфер допустимого размера, скажем, 4MB и скачивать в него и отправлять. Из ResponseBody получаете InputStream дальше его записываете через буфер в OutputStream запроса на отправку и дело в шляпе.

Как-то так можно сделать это на уровне потоков данных:

```
final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
    os.write(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно понимать, что операционная система Android ограничивает оперативную память для вашего приложения. В среднем на практике выделяется 30-40 MB. Вы можете увеличить этот показатель, дописав в манифесте largeHeap="true", но обычно если Ваше приложение не занимается тяжелыми вещами по-типу обработки изображений, то надобности в этом возникать не должно. А если и возникает, то советую поискать возможные утечки памяти.

Что касается загрузки изображений и других файлов прямиком в оперативную память, как хотите сделать Вы, это чревато OutOfMemory, по описанным выше причинам. Поэтому советую оставить всё как есть, если это работает.